# Connect clients to portable PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, portability

First of all: my only experience with SQL is by SQLite which is a server-less engine. I'm new on all this client/server story.

Summarizing my goal: I need to read/write from/into a PosgreSQL database from different computers. Those computers (all with Windows 7 or 10 installed) share the same network but I cannot install any software on them.

My idea was to download the portable PostgreSQL server and save it in a network shared directory (e.g. Y:\PortableProject) so all computers have access to the executable files and to the Data folder containing the databases. Suppose the network IP is 192.170.1.200 (from `ipconfig` command), here are the steps I tried to do so far:

1. In order to allow IP 192.170.1.200 being a host, open `pg_hba.conf` file and add the following line in the EOF

   ```
   host    all             all             192.170.1.200/32                 trust
   ```
2. In order to give permission to all computers accessing the server, open `postgresql.conf` and update `listen_addresses` to `*`

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'
   ```
3. Open the command prompt in one computer (e.g. computer A) and start the server from a prompt with the following command:

   ```
   "Y:\PortableProject\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin\pg_ctl.exe" start -D "Y:\PortableProject\PostgreSQLPortable\Data\data"
   ```
4. Proceed with writing and reading in all computers. E.g., on computer B, open its prompt command and read all information on table `tabtest` from database `dbtest` (supposing they exist) with the command:

   ```
   "Y:\PortableProject\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.170.1.200 -p 5432 -U postgres -d dbtest -c "SELECT * FROM tabtest"
   ```
5. Close the connection on computer A:

   ```
   "Y:\PortableProject\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin\pg_ctl.exe" stop -D "Y:\PortableProject\PostgreSQLPortable\Data\data"
   ```

The problem occurs on step 4. Even if I run it from computer A, I get the following error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "192.170.1.200" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Am I doing it completely wrong? Is it even possible to reach my goal?

Comment: Dont know why you use portable postgre instead regular one. Your problem is read the db from different pc and regular one do that very good and you dont need install sw on those pc. Portable is for when you need take your db outside the office location.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know how to proceed by following your suggestion. How can I read from a postgre database with no installation and no portable postgres? I also need to insert and update from all computers in the network.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand your problem. But If you dont want install anything develop a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the server running on host "192.170.1.200" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

That mean the server is running in `192.170.1.200`, now you are executing from the server pc or from a different pc?

The `pg_hba.conf` is to list what other address / users are allow to access that sever.

So if you are access from the same pc you use

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

For external address you use something like

```
host    all             all             192.170.1.1/24          trust
```

This will allow access to pc with the following IP address range. **[IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.170.1.1&mask1=24&mask2=)**

```
HostMin:   192.170.1.1   
HostMax:   192.170.1.254
```